# How to access body from POST request (using 'fetch()') inside my Extbase Controller

Tags: javascript, http, typo3, service-worker, extbase

I'm sending a POST request via fetch() from my JavaScript Service-Worker to my TYPO3 Extbase controller action.
The controller then goes on to process the data, but I can't find a way to get the body data.

I'm calling the Action through an Extbase RouteEnhancer, but I think this shouldn't affect my Problem.

*in the Service Worker:* [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)

```
fetch("myDomain.de/my/route/Enhancer/", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ cookieValue: cookie})
})
```

*in the Controller* [extbase](/questions/tagged/extbase) [php](/questions/tagged/php)

```
    public function syncAction()
    {
        ?? Get Body from fetch() here??
        return file_get_contents('php://input'); <-- is empty
    }
```

---

I want to retrieve the body data from fetch.

I've tried:

```
$request = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_REQUEST'];
$data = $request->getParsedBody();
```

returns *NULL*

```
$data = $this->request->getParsedBody();
```

returns *NULL*

```
file_get_contents('php://input');
```

is empty

---

Am I missing something?
Is this the right way to approach or may there be a better solution to send the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Since TYPO3v11](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/11.3/Feature-94428-ExtbaseRequestImplementsServerRequestInterface.html) you can access `$this->request` for the (decorated) request. This way you can access the request body:

```php
$this->request->getBody()
```

However, since this will only give you the body as raw stream, you can use this convenience wrapper:

```php
$this->request->getParsedBody()
```

Comment: How does 'getParsedBody' work? When I POST with body: "Hello World!" getParsedBody returns null. request->getBody worked fine.

Comment: Yes, this only works with structured data since this method handles such kind of request bodies by definition. Plain scalar values are not covered and must be retrieved from the body instead.